# Allure 2 report passing in an object as parameter to an allure.step in Python

Tags: python, allure

Hi all i'm using Allure 2 for my test reports and i noticed that whenever i pass in an object allure prints it as follows:

```
<models.myobj.myobj object at 0x10765c820>

class myobj:
    def __str__(self):
        return "my own message for this obj" #this is what i want to print
```

is it possible to have it print like in the example above? Allure does not seem to call the **str** method of the object. So i'm not sure how to change the message

Comment: It should be `def __str__(self)`

Comment: ye sorry i closed my editor so i typed in the post, i fixed it now :)